# .dll library missing error

Tags: wampserver, msvcr100.dll

I've just installed Wampserver 64 and I get this error while running "api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer". I dowloaded the file, pasted it in sysWOW64 directory but still getting the same error. 
How do I fix this?

Comment: SysWOW64 contains 32-bit .dlls. Try putting it into System32.

Comment: Solved but another issue just pops out.This time _api-ms-win-core-timezone-|1-1-0.dll_ is missing. Do I download this one too and try the same?

Comment: Of course. But maybe they are located somewhere in that software's installation folder so you don't have to look them up online.